# Carthage version for compatible with patches

Tags: ios, carthage

From Carthage documentation:

Carthage supports several kinds of version requirements:

1. `>= 1.0` for “at least version 1.0”
2. `~> 1.0` for “compatible with version 1.0”
3. `== 1.0` for “exactly version 1.0”

Compatibility is determined according to [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

According to this, is there a way I can get a version definition in a way that it will work for compatible patches versions?

For example, something to specify `1.2.x` in which all the versions from `1.2.x` to 1.3.0 (without including it) will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it works only with *minors*.

If you add `~> 1.2.1` to your *cartfile*, any version from `1.2.1` up to, but not including `2.0`, is considered compatible.
Likewise, if you add `~> 2.0` then Carthage will use a version `2.0` or later, but less than `3.0`.

Comment: Ok, that's what I supposed :(. Thanks